# QT Is there any way to convert a map containing paths and values to JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt, qmap

I have a QSettings map composed of path(key) and value. What I need to do is convert the paths from the map into actual json objects and arrays and save them into a json file.

Writing from the to the json was pretty straight forward, however it saves each path as a key and that is not good for what I need.

Is there any algorithm or tool that might allow me to do this.

My map looks like this

```
"BaclightActivationTime" 20000
"return/bicycle/color" "red"
"return/bicycle/price" 19.95
"return/input[0]/author" "Nigel Rees"
"return/input[0]/category" "reference"
"return/input[0]/price" 8.95
"return/input[0]/title" "Sayings of the Century"
"return/input[1]/author" "Evelyn Waugh"
"return/input[1]/category" "fiction"
"return/input[1]/price" 12.99
"return/input[1]/title" "Sword of Honour"
"title" "Practica json"
```

and I would like it to look like this

```
{

  "title": "Practica json",
  "BaclightActivationTime": 20000,
  "return": {
   "input": [
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",  &*alt comentariu*&
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh", &*inca un comentariu*&
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
      }
    }
 }
```

my current write function looks like this

```
bool writeJsonFile(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {

    device.write( QJsonDocument( QJsonObject::fromVariantMap( map ) ).toJson() );
    return true;
}
```

device holds the path of the json file.

EDIT ----------------------------

added the code which reads the data and builds the map

this function reads the data

```
bool readJsonFile( QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map)
{
QString string = device.readAll();

QByteArray jsonBytes = string.toLocal8Bit();
auto document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonBytes);

//various ifs checking is the document exists and can be opened

   if (document.isObject()){
        QJsonObject jsonObj = document.object();
        readObject("", 0, map, jsonObj);

   }
   else if(document.isArray()){
       QJsonArray jArr = document.array();
       readArray("", 0, map, jArr);

   }


return true;
}
```

these functions parse the data and add it to the map

```
QSettings::SettingsMap readObject(QString path, int level, QSettings::SettingsMap &map, QJsonObject jsonObj){
int maxLevel = 9001;
foreach(const QString& key, jsonObj.keys()) {
    if(level == maxLevel){
        qDebug()<<"You are going too deep ";
        break;
    }
    else{
       QJsonValue value = jsonObj.value(key);
       if(path.length()) path += "/";
       if(value.isArray()){
          QJsonArray jArray = value.toArray();
           path += key;
           level++;
           readArray(path, level, map, jArray);
           path.chop(key.length()+1);
           level--;
       }
       if(value.isObject()){
           QJsonObject jObject = value.toObject();
           path += key;
           level++;
           readObject(path, level, map, jObject);
           path.chop(key.length()+1);
           level--;
    }

       if(value.isString()){
           path += key;
           level++;
           map.insert(path, value.toVariant());
           qDebug()<<path<<value.toString()<<" level "<<level;
           path.chop(key.length()+1);
           level--;
       }

       if(value.isDouble()){
           path += key;
           level++;
           map.insert(path, value.toVariant());
           qDebug()<<path<<value.toDouble()<<" level "<<level;
           path.chop(key.length()+1);
           level--;
       }
    }


}

return map;

}
```

readArray is virtually identical, only it takes an array instead of an object.

Comment: You say: *My map looks like this*, you could show how you build the map.

Comment: I read the data from another JSON file, parse it and build the path by adding / or [] and the key, then I save the path and value in map which I use for other functions I need.

Comment: You want me to reverse the method that converts json to map. I am right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's what I need to do, yes.